# How to generate 100 random variables (columns) with 1000 rows of random generated numbersin each column?

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, correlation

I'm trying to generate a random dataset with as much as 100 variables as the title says.

I then want to consider a desired correlation matrix with n rows/columns, and construct a Cholesky decomposition matrix based on the previous matrix (2).

I then want to Matrix-multiply the original dataset (1) times the Cholesky decomposition matrix so I can calculate the relative position of each Cholesky-decomposed element within each variable (column) to be able to rearrange the original dataset by the ranking order given on the previous ranking order.

Ideally, this should be solved using in-memory arrays and not in Excel cells. I was able to write the following Cholesky code:

```
Function Cholesky(oMatrix As Range)
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, N As Integer
    Dim arrMatrix() As Double, arrLower() As Double, pValue As Double
    N = oMatrix.Columns.Count
    ReDim arrMatrix(1 To N, 1 To N)
    ReDim arrLower(1 To N, 1 To N)
    
    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To N
            arrMatrix(i, j) = oMatrix(i, j).Value
            arrLower(i, j) = 0
        Next j
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To N
        For j = 1 To N
            pValue = arrMatrix(i, j)
            For k = 1 To i - 1
                pValue = pValue - arrLower(i, k) * arrLower(j, k)
            Next k
            If i = j Then
                arrLower(i, i) = Sqr(pValue)
            ElseIf i > j Then
                arrLower(j, i) = pValue / arrLower(i, i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Cholesky = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrLower)
End Function
```

The excel picture:

[image]

I cant seem to automate the rest for this algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are most welcome.Probably worth spelling out the missing part of your implementation of the algorithm. If there are several parts missing, focus this question just on one part.

Comment: @QHarr im basically trying to vba automate to insert 100 variables (columns) with 1000 rows in each columns but i dont know how i can name them all like to generate a name to them

Comment: you can't generate program variable names on the fly if that is part of what you mean. You can generate strings for example that form part of output.

Comment: can i generate the strings then change them to a variable or like call them a variable @QHarr

Comment: Not sure why you would need variables generated in this way. Working with matrices can't you just use indices and loops to populate?

Comment: Sheet columns are natively named and numbered by Excel. Column("A") is also Column(1). So you can use either their given name or use their number to create a name, such as Arr(1) = Columns(1).

Comment: @nothing Variable names are hard coded and cannot be dynamic. If you need 100 variables create an array `Dim MyArray(1 To 100) As Double` so you have 100 variable placese in `MyArray` that you can acces like `MyArray(1)`, `MyArray(2)` etc.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ ah i see i will look into it thank you very much

Comment: @Variatus ah didnt know that thank you for the info

Comment: @QHarr https://www.screencast.com/t/OKZIk1H7Vhr7 if you can watch the first couple of seconds to understand what i want to do that would be highly appreciated

Comment: Ok... I will have proper look tonight but from quick look this morning you need a dynamic array. You declare the array and then ReDim the array to the appropriate dimensions (1 to numRows, 1 to numCols) where numRows > =1 and <= 50000, I think he said, and numCol >=1 and <= 100. I'll watch whole thing tonight. Not sure yet how the random values are being generated but not difficult in terms of generating and populating a dynamic array with random values.

Comment: Isn't the code shown what you were given and the rest of the implementation is homework?

Comment: @QHarr thanks for the respond and sorry for the lateness, the code in the video is for the algorithm not on how to generate but its okay its over now